# AjaxUpload: why do I have to click twice?

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, click, livequery

The code below  uploads files to the server using AjaxUpload.2.0.min.js

But you need to click several times on the “Add File” button for the OS window (where to pick the file you want to upload) to show, instead of clicking just once.

Also,  if you click once in the link and then you move the mouse out of the red area and click (out of #upload_files), and  last you click back in the link, it works, the OS window opens .. but why do I have to do this? Is that AjaxUpload will not be initially bound in the .livequery call? then, how do I bound it?

Please focus on this, on the OS window to show with the first click of the mouse. The rest of the programming it's working fine in my server.

The .js are uploaded into github to make the code easy to test, but in the real case they are in my machine.

Thanks a lot

```
<head>
<style>
#upload_files{color: #fff; background:#F32201; border:1px solid #7E9DB9; padding:2px;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://gist.github.com/raw/6dd585079502f138d87e/7c243080233761859937d52195b670602731a379/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://gist.github.com/raw/eeb2fe78f63ab80b626d/5be66e749b19fbb5b7c8814bf72a98c083f2aaaf/jquery.livequery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://gist.github.com/raw/826bff2445c8533dd7fc/797734455959ef27796b6770c95a7b39049ae6e9/AjaxUpload.2.0.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {

    function uploadFiles(){   
        new AjaxUpload('#upload_files', {
            action: 'whereToUploadInServer.php',
        });     

    }//end uploadFiles

           $("#upload_files").livequery("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        uploadFiles();
        //debugger ;
    }); 
}); //end document ready

    </script>


  </head>
  <body>
       <div><a href="#" id="upload_files">Add File</a></div> <br>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the ajaxupload component is not fully operational at this time according to the docs on Github. The author suggests using the new qq.FileUploader plugin instead.

Here's an example that brings up the file dialog immediately after clicking the div element.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/253qT/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the log in, I'm who started the post: thanks!!!!!!!!!!!! you saved my project!!

Comment: Ah! That is good news. I ran into a similar issue myself about 8 to 9 months ago. One note: it is customary on SO to accept the answer of the respondent providing the best answer/solution.